# e.UserState not available in Completed event in windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to implement a callback for the method I defined in the ModelLib.cs and it has the following code.But e.UserSTate is not available.IS there a way we can replace it with something.

```
public class TrackingDetailsModel
{
    public void GetCurrentLocation()
    {
       GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
       watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(this.watcher_PositionChanged);       

    }
}

  private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {

        Action<LocationInfo> target = (Action<LocationInfo>)e.UserState;//user state here is not recognized..
     }
```

The LocaionInfo class is defined in UtilLib.cs like below :

```
 public class LocationInfo
   { 
    public string Altitude{ get; set; }
    public string Longitude{ get; set; }
    public string Latitude{ get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Can you show the line where you subscribe to the `PositionChanged` event? Where are you instantiating your `LocationInfo` object?

Comment: Sorry. I updated the original post to include the same .

Comment: as far as i'm aware, the GeoCoordinate class does not contain a UserState property, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.aspx  is there any reason why you need a custom LoctionInfo class? e.Position.Location should give you all you need and can be passed into your action/function

Comment: I am following MVVM model for the app I am developing.So I am trying to put the code that gets the data from ModelClass.And declared the class LocationInfo entity so that at the calling code I can resue the same structure to parse the data..Looks like I have to have this code back in ViewModel itself..